# How to calculate a slope of lines by factor

Tags: r

I do not know how to get a slope of a line by factor. Below are my data;

```
ID  x   y
1   2.43136376  0.38584994
1   2.68124124  0.42833589
1   2.35218252  0.37147102
1   2.51851394  0.40114436
1   2.38021124  0.3766155
1   2.62324929  0.41883956
1   2.97543181  0.47355
1   1.60205999  0.20467877
1   2.97772361  0.47388438
4   2.79934055  0.44705574
4   2.8920946   0.46121249
4   2.76715587  0.44203362
4   2.88366144  0.45994427
4   2.65321251  0.42377204
4   2.07918125  0.31789235
4   2.88081359  0.45951516
4   2.07918125  0.31789235
4   2.64345268  0.42217154
4   2.43136376  0.38584994
4   2.51188336  0.39999947
4   2.81954394  0.45017887
4   2.11394335  0.32509335
```

The slope for ID1 and ID4 are 5.10 and 5.65, respectively.

Do you all know how to calculate and extract a slope of a line by factor efficiently?

Comment: Welcome to SO and R. To make your question easily reproducible please put your data into a useable object for example like this: df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c("a", "b", "c")) obviously with your own data! This will help those who want to help you. It also helps if you say what you have tried so far and what you have looked for. Have you read the guidance on [ask] a qood question and how to set out a [reprex]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `lm`

```
slopes <- sapply(split(df,df$ID), function(v) lm(x~y,v)$coefficients["y"])
```

such that

```
> slopes
     1.y      4.y 
5.099948 5.650415
```